# Wcf Rest Service error while passing stream

Tags: wcf, wcf-rest, jira-rest-api

I am able to hit the method in wcf rest service using postman.

but i am using JIRA webhook when i hit the API it gives me 400 error

```
  Client error - 400 when posting to web hook at 'http://localhost:12456/JiraRestWebhook.svc/GetData/TES-217?user_id=james&user_key=jamesD'
```

my method is as follows :

```
     [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json
            , UriTemplate = "GetData/{value}"
            )]
    string GetData(string value, Stream c);
```

i am successfully able to hit it using postman. the request also contains the Raw Data.

but my JIRA webhook is giving this error while updating/creating any issue.

Please note:- if i remove Stream Param from the method . then my service is able to give me result.

Answer (score 0):

Few things worth correcting in your WCF interface:
1. First you should consider adding Method = "GET" in WebInvoke.
2. Since you are using "GetData/{value}" you request URL should only look like this. {value} is the place where it will pick the value string you passed as parameter.

```
'http://localhost:12456/JiraRestWebhook.svc/GetData/jamesD'
```

1. Not sure why you are passing  Stream c along with other parameter. If you are looking to pass a json request here are few things you need to change in your WCF service.

Your operation contract should look like this:

```
 [OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json
        , UriTemplate = "GetData" //this can be anything like GetDate/Json/GeMeData
        )]
string GetData(Stream c);
```

your GetData now has the jSON request you need to transform to object using deserialization.

Comment: everything with my code is correct as i explained earlier that if i post to my url with Postman restclient in chrome. it is working as expected but same code doesn`t work if i use a webhook in JIRA.